# Debug an error in "Statistics.corr" in mlib library

Tags: pyspark

I wanted to compare the performance of two correlation methods, Pearson and spearman for big data set.  Therefore, I used mlib library in pyspark.  However, for some cases Pearson correlation gave me nan value where as spearman worked well. To double check that the problem is not in my dataset I run some example manually and Pearson correlation had a value not nan as I got using mlib correlation function.  Therefore, I am seeking for help in order to identify the error here or to give me some hints on how to debug the error in this function

Following is a simple exapmle for calculating the correltaion between two arrays:

```
  x=[-18,-18,-18,-17.95,-17.9,-17.95,-18,-18,-18,-18,-17.95,-17.9,-18,-18.1,-18.05,-18,-18,-18,-18.05,-18.1,-18.1,-18.1,-18.05,-18,-18,-18,-18.05,-18.1,-18.1,-18.1]

  x=np.asarray(x)

  x=sc.parallelize(x)

  x.count()
     30

  y=[4.10E-07,3.65E-07,3.20E-07,3.20E-07,3.20E-07,3.15E-07,3.10E-07,3.30E-07,3.45E-07,3.60E-07,4.60E-07,5.60E-07,6.35E-07,7.10E-07,6.80E-07,6.50E-07,5.20E-07,3.90E-07,4.15E-07,4.40E-07,5.05E-07,5.70E-07,4.90E-07,4.10E-07,3.50E-07,2.90E-07,2.85E-07,2.80E-07,3.40E-07,4.00E-07]
  y=np.asarray(y)

  y=sc.parallelize(y)

  y.count()
     30

 In [172]: pearson=Statistics.corr(x,y,method='pearson')
 2019-04-16 16:16:41 WARN  PearsonCorrelation:66 - Pearson 
  correlation matrix contains NaN values.

 In [173]: pearson
 Out[173]: nan

 In [174]: spearman=Statistics.corr(x,y,method='spearman')

  In [175]: spearman
  Out[175]: -0.21201144954413315
```

It should be noted that the actual pearson correlation value for the input is -0.1945

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like underflow might be catching up with Spark somewhere, one way to overcome it is to normalize the data like so

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics

x=[-18,-18,-18,-17.95,-17.9,-17.95,-18,-18,-18,-18,-17.95,-17.9,-18,-18.1,-18.05,-18,-18,-18,-18.05,-18.1,-18.1,-18.1,-18.05,-18,-18,-18,-18.05,-18.1,-18.1,-18.1]

x=normalize(x).reshape(-1,1)
x=sc.parallelize(x)

y=[4.10E-07,3.65E-07,3.20E-07,3.20E-07,3.20E-07,3.15E-07,3.10E-07,3.30E-07,3.45E-07,3.60E-07,4.60E-07,5.60E-07,6.35E-07,7.10E-07,6.80E-07,6.50E-07,5.20E-07,3.90E-07,4.15E-07,4.40E-07,5.05E-07,5.70E-07,4.90E-07,4.10E-07,3.50E-07,2.90E-07,2.85E-07,2.80E-07,3.40E-07,4.00E-07]
y=normalize(y).reshape(-1,1)
y=sc.parallelize(y)

Statistics.corr(x,y,method='pearson')

Out[16]: -0.1945022009093267
```

But not sure in your case as you said you have rather large data set and how feasible applying normalization is going to be for you